# How can I get my nav bar to scroll down, when I scroll down the page

Tags: html, css

I have already tried every tutorial I can find, but none of them seem to work for me. Maybe I wasn't doing it right, but none of them seem to work. Please help.

How can I make my nav bar to scroll down, I don't need anything fancy, I just want a basic and simple scroll down nav bar.

CSS:

I got this from W3school, the .sticky and JS parts. But it don't work.

```
#main-navbar {
  left: 100%;
  right: 100%;
  background-color: #FFF;
  z-index: 910;

}
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}


.sticky + .content {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
```

JS:

```
// When the user scrolls the page, execute myFunction 
    window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

// Get the navbar
    var navbar = document.getElementById("main-navbar");

// Get the offset position of the navbar
    var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

// Add the sticky class to the navbar when you reach its scroll position. Remove "sticky" when you leave the scroll position
    function myFunction() {
      if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
        navbar.classList.add("sticky")
      } else {
        navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
      }
    }

This is the original.
```

CSS:

```
#main-navbar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #FFF;
  z-index: 910;
}
```

html:

```
        <nav id="main-navbar">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">

<!-- Nav menu -->
                <ul class="navbar-menu nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="indexx.php">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li class="has-dropdown"><a href="#">Causes</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown">
                            <li><a href="single-cause.html">A</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="has-dropdown"><a href="#">Events</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown">
                            <li><a href="single-event.html">A</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="has-dropdown"><a href="#">Member</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown">
                            <li><a href="signup.php">Sign Up</a></li>
                            <li><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="report.php">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
                <!-- Nav menu -->
            </div>
        </nav>
```

Comment: The page you got the code from, would that be [this page](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_navbar_sticky.asp)? If so, it works, so have you made any changes to the code when copying it to your page?

Comment: yes it is, no, I didn't do anything changes. Maybe because my web don't have a header? In my web, the navbar is at the very top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Note: Internet Explorer, Edge 15 and earlier versions do not support sticky positioning. Safari requires a -webkit- prefix (see example below). You must also specify at least one of top, right, bottom or left for sticky positioning to work.

[CSS position:sticky - Can I use... Support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky)

[Cross Browser sticky](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Browser_compatibility)

```js
// When the user scrolls the page, execute myFunction 
    window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

// Get the navbar
    var navbar = document.getElementById("main-navbar");

// Get the offset position of the navbar
    var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

// Add the sticky class to the navbar when you reach its scroll position. Remove "sticky" when you leave the scroll position
    function myFunction() {
      if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
        navbar.classList.add("sticky")
      } else {
        navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
      }
    }
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 4000px;
}
 
.header {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

#main-navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
}

#main-navbar  ul li  a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px ;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#main-navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

#main-navbar ul.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.sticky + .content {
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.dropdown {
    display: none;
 }
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h2>Scroll Down</h2>
  <p>Scroll down to see the sticky effect.</p>
</div>        
        
  <nav id="main-navbar">
      <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header"> </div>
<!-- Nav menu -->
          <ul class="navbar-menu nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li><a href="indexx.php">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
              <li class="has-dropdown"><a href="#">Causes</a>
                  <ul class="dropdown">
                      <li><a href="single-cause.html">A</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="has-dropdown"><a href="#">Events</a>
                  <ul class="dropdown">
                      <li><a href="single-event.html">A</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="has-dropdown"><a href="#">Member</a>
                  <ul class="dropdown">
                      <li><a href="signup.php">Sign Up</a></li>
                      <li><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="report.php">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
          <!-- Nav menu -->
      </div>
  </nav>
        
<div class="content">
  <h3>Sticky Navigation Example</h3>
  <p>The navbar will stick to the top when you reach its scroll position.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Verrryyyy nice)

Comment: My web don't have a header, the navbar is at the very top. So, does it make any difference?

Comment: If you always want the navbar at the top, you don't need this trick; you can just set `position:fixed` and be done with it.

Comment: In "sticky" you must have a content before the nav menu. As long as the scroll ....
Otherwise, you do not need sticky.
My dear friend @Mr Lister correctly point out.
You can use this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_navbar_shrink_scroll.asp)

Answer (score 0):

you don't need javascript for this one

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  padding: 20px;
}

.navbar-header  .navbar-menu {
  display: flex;
 }
 
 .navbar-menu .dropdown {
    display: none;
 }
 
.page {
    min-height: 4000px;
}
 
 /*  HERE IS WHAT YOU NEED*/
 
 /* set the position to the main parent of the navbar as relative*/
 .page {
  position: relative;
 }
 
 /*set the positionj of the navbar as sticky and give it the top:0;*/
 #main-navbar {
  position: sticky;
  top:0;
 }
```

```html
<div class="page">
<nav id="main-navbar">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">

<!-- Nav menu -->
                <ul class="navbar-menu nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="indexx.php">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li class="has-dropdown"><a href="#">Causes</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown">
                            <li><a href="single-cause.html">A</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="has-dropdown"><a href="#">Events</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown">
                            <li><a href="single-event.html">A</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="has-dropdown"><a href="#">Member</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown">
                            <li><a href="signup.php">Sign Up</a></li>
                            <li><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="report.php">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
                <!-- Nav menu -->
            </div>
        </nav>
       </div>
```